# Known patterns for sharding connections on to servers based on teams or rooms?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, server, multiplayer

I'm designing the servers for a system that puts groups of 50 people together. It's important that those 50 people all get routed to the same server, but I need to support a dynamic number of servers, and be resilient to any given server failing without notice.

I can think of several approaches here but haven't been able to find any existing solutions or patterns to follow. Does this problem have a name and a set of generalized solutions?

Comment: You mean like [application-controlled session stickyness on load balancers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-sticky-sessions.html#enable-sticky-sessions-application)?

Comment: Session stickiness is not enough because I also need to group clients on to specific servers in the first place. It's not enough to make sure they always go back to the same server.

Comment: I think the mechanism is quite similar.

Answer (score 1):

Photon Server (with LoadBalancing framework) is implementing this pattern:
https://www.photonengine.com/en-US/OnPremise
http://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/onpremise/current/applications/loadbalancing/application

You can easily test it out with PUN in Unity:
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/1786